# Can I use one 12 V, 2 A power adapter to power two LED light strips, or do I need to get a 12 V, 4 A adapter to power both?

Tags: power-supply

I'd like to link two 20' LED light strips together. Each strip comes with a 12 V, 2 A power adapter.

The adapters that came with these sets make a humming noise, so I want to replace them. Rather than have to buy two new power adapters, I'm wondering if I can just buy a single (but quieter) adapter for both sets. If that would not be powerful enough, could I buy one 12 V, 4 A adapter or maybe even a 5 A one for more power?

I have eight LED sets in total for my project and I want to link two together for four different places so that would be a total of eight new power adapters or just four if what I'm asking above will work. Please let me know.

Comment: maybe the adapters are humming because they are nearing overload

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can power several strips using more powerful adapter. Wire two of strips in parallel. You do not need to care about brighness changes, as internaly stripe consist of substrings where LEDs connected in series, thus brightness is balanced.

Answer (score 1):

How much do the LED sets draw. That will determine how much current you need to supply. As long as the power adapter is capable of supplying more current then required at the LED required voltage it will be OK. A adapter that will supply more current will probably run cooler and last a lot longer. Be careful with the wire sizes you use, the higher the gauge number the smaller the wire and the greater its resistance will be. On the LED strips I worked with a difference of about 0.5 volts started becoming noticeable. You can put as many LED strips on an adapter as you want so long as the total current is less than the adapter's rating. You have 8 strips assuming 2A that is 16 amps. The two closest power supplies would be a 15A and a 20A. 15A is not strong enough the 20 or larger would be fine.